# Why does this jsfiddle not see my module/controller?

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I have [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38t7W/).  It does not recognize the controller. I have a terrible time creating jsfiddles. What am I missing? I can make it work by removing the module entirely and having the controller just be a function. But that's not how applications are written so it is unhelpful.

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ZootCtrl">
    <button ng-model="model" ng-click="inc()">{{model.count}}</button>
</div>

// this is in the javascript pane
var app = angular.module('myapp', [])
    .controller('ZootCtrl', [$scope, function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        count: 0
    };

    $scope.inc = function () {
        $scope.model.count += 1;
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your fiddle. See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/A6rTN/

There were two issues.
First quotes around `'$scope'` were missing in the controller dependencies.
Secondly the load mechanism for jsfiddle needed to be changed to `no wrap - in body`

Comment: Thank you. I *really* thought I had it that way in a previous incarnation.  But apparently not. So the javascript was not wired up to the dom, then. What does `no wrap - in body` do? I always just try them all :-/

Comment: This setting decides when to load your scripts. See the jsfiddle documentation.